# Linked PDF's text showing up on webpage on Apple devices

Tags: html, pdf, safari

When viewed on an iPod or Mac (haven't tested other Apple devices), this webpage displays the text of a linked PDF over the text and photo of the original page where the PDF is linked from. I've tried making the link open in a blank window and that didn't resolve the issue (as I thought perhaps it was thinking it was embedded.

The code itself is: `<p align="left" class="style1"><a href="Baxter_M&amp;E_May2013_23Oct2.pdf" target="_blank">May 2013     Short Course Info</a> </p>`

Background:A few years ago my wife built a simple webpage for a client who wanted a certain style webpage (antique looking?). Neither of us are programmers but I know enough HTML and CSS to error check and such. The website is old and not representative of our skills/abilities (wanted to get that out of the way now).

The full code for the page:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Course Information</title>
<link href="irving.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style3 {font-size: 16px}
-->
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function mmLoadMenus() {
  if (window.mm_menu_0115210737_0) return;
  window.mm_menu_0115210737_0 = new Menu("root",96,18,"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",12,"#030303","#FFFFFF","#FFFFFF","#000000","left","middle",3,0,1000,-5,7,true,true,true,0,true,true);
  mm_menu_0115210737_0.addMenuItem("Biography","location='bio.html'");
  mm_menu_0115210737_0.addMenuItem("Publications","location='publications.html'");
  mm_menu_0115210737_0.addMenuItem("I.J.'s&nbsp;Food","location='moreinfo.html'");
  mm_menu_0115210737_0.addMenuItem("Photos","location='photos.html'");
   mm_menu_0115210737_0.hideOnMouseOut=true;
   mm_menu_0115210737_0.bgColor='#300022';
   mm_menu_0115210737_0.menuBorder=1;
   mm_menu_0115210737_0.menuLiteBgColor='#300022';
   mm_menu_0115210737_0.menuBorderBgColor='#030303';

mm_menu_0115210737_0.writeMenus();
} // mmLoadMenus()
//-->
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="mm_menu.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">mmLoadMenus();</script>
<table width="794" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <!--DWLayoutTable-->
  <tr>
    <td height="79" colspan="4" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000" class="title"><img src="images/banner-black1.jpg" width="590" height="48" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#3366FF" class="a">
    <td height="22" colspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#3366FF" class="navigation" id="navigation"><a href="index.html">Home </a><a href="bio.html" name="link1" id="link1" onmouseover="MM_showMenu(window.mm_menu_0115210737_0,0,19,null,'link1')" onmouseout="MM_startTimeout();">I. J.  Pflug </a><a href="course.html">Course Info</a><a href="books.html">Order Books</a><a href="resources.html">Resources</a><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="78" rowspan="3" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="88" colspan="2" valign="top" class="style1"><h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>Information Regarding the Microbiology and Engineering of  Sterilization Processes Course</h1></td>
    <td width="60" rowspan="4" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="317" height="144" valign="top" background="Baxter M&amp;ECseApr08,12Dec07.pdf"><br />
        <p align="left"><span class="style1"><strong class="style1 style3">1. Upcoming Courses:</strong></span></p>
        <p align="left" class="style1"><a href="Baxter_M&amp;E_May2013_23Oct2.pdf" target="_blank">May 2013     Short Course Info</a> </p>
        <p align="left" class="style1">May 1-3 , 2013  <br />
        Baxter International Headquarters<br />
      Deerfield, IL </p>
        <p align="left"><a href="M&amp;E,Dec08 CrsAnn&amp;Reg ,Mar0.pdf" target="_blank"></a><strong><br />
        <br />
    </strong></p></td>
    <td width="372" valign="top"><div align="left"></div>
    <img src="images/class1.jpg" width="289" height="193" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" valign="top" class="style1"><p align="left" class="style2">&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="1774" valign="top"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```